Do All Adventurers League Characters Gain a Magic Item At Level 5?
I was recently playing an Adventurers League adventure and leveled up from 4 to 5. The DM informed me that at level 5, I had the option of choosing one of the permanent magic items in the Season 14 Guide.
However, the Season 14 Adventurers League Guide states:

STARTING PLAY AT 5TH LEVEL You may choose to create a 5th level
character instead of starting at 1st level. As a 5th level character,
you may choose one of the following magic items to possess. (etc).

Does this mean that ALL characters get to select a magic item from the list when reaching 5th level, or ONLY characters that are created at 5th level?

Yes, you always gain a magic item at 5th level
This is in the Player's Guide, on page 2 under "Leveling Up":

Once you achieve 5th level, you may choose a magic item
as presented in “Starting Play at 5th Level” above

So once you achieve 5th level, you can select a magic item from the same selection of items that you could select when you create a 5th level starting character. Your DM handled this correctly.
